# Rails Error Can't Find freedesktop.org.xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, new-project

I've had some issues starting a new RAILS project, where I'm getting an error that there is a missing file `/usr/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml`. There was a connection with the mimemagic dependencies, and I found this issue on GitHub about the mimemagic version and licensing - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/41750

Wondering if anybody else ran into the issue, and could explain what is going on.

I'm using rbenv with ruby version: 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-darwin19], and rails 6.1.3

Here is the error message in the command line:

```
Installing railties 6.1.3
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/nico/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.7/ext/mimemagic
/Users/nico/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/ruby -I/Users/nico/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -rrubygems
/Users/nico/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake
RUBYARCHDIR\=/Users/nico/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/3.0.0/mimemagic-0.3.7
RUBYLIBDIR\=/Users/nico/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/3.0.0/mimemagic-0.3.7
rake aborted!
Could not find MIME type database in the following locations: ["/usr/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml",
"/opt/homebrew/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml"]

Ensure you have either installed the shared-mime-types package for your distribution, or 
obtain a version of freedesktop.org.xml and set FREEDESKTOP_MIME_TYPES_PATH to the location of that file.

Tasks: TOP => default
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1
```

Thanks,
Nico

Answer (score 55):

Found some links to shared-mime-info on the GitHub link I posted, and I solved the issue by running the command below and starting a new project:

```
brew install shared-mime-info
```

Comment: Yup, I had same issue trying to install rails itself. `brew install shared-mime-info` installed a bunch of dependencies but it ultimately worked for me!

Comment: Worked for me on Mac Silicon processor

Comment: This worked for me!!

Answer (score 5):

If you are on ubuntu OS you can run below command

`sudo apt-get install shared-mime-info`

Answer (score 1):

If migrating data from an Intel Mac (or an M1 Mac running Rosetta 2) to an M1, note that mimemagic will cache the old directory, so in addition to `brew install shared-mime-info`, you'll want to run:

```
gem uninstall mimemagic
gem install mimemagic
```